# Run firefox in headless with FirefoxBinary.StartProfile()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem as follows
I try using `FirefoxBinary.StartProfile()` to open **firefox** in **headless mode**. And I received an error.
This is my code

```
var path = @"C:\Users\camera\Downloads\FirefoxPortable\App\Firefox\firefox.exe";

var abc = @"C:\Users\camera\Desktop\FirefoxPortable\App\DefaultData\profile\bookmarks.html";
string[] arr2 = { "--headless"};
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(abc);
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(path);  
//err here      
binary.StartProfile(profile, "--headless");
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
```

In line `Fbinary.StartProfile(profile, "--headless")`, I received an error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: You must set both the property name and value: XRE_PROFILE_PATH,
```

I do not know how to solve this problem. I passed the correct order of parameters

It is difficult to run firefox portable with some mode by C#. I see Java can do this easily. But I like C#

Help me, please! Thanks

Comment: When you tried the same in JAVA , did that work for you ? and also tell us your browser version , selenium version , and gecko driver version.

Comment: I use latest version.  My error is FirefoxProfile.ProfileDirectory return null. So 
there is nothing value for  XRE_PROFILE_PATH. I know that because of this document
  
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Firefox/FirefoxBinary.cs


And I try resolve it by this ducoment:


https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Firefox/FirefoxProfile.cs



I still can not resolve it. Because I learn C # is not good. So I do not understand the document above to be able to resolve my problems.

Answer (score 0):

If all you’re trying to do is start Firefox in headless mode, all you should need to do is something similar to the following:

```
// WARNING! Code written from memory
// without the benefit of an IDE.
// Syntax may be slightly incorrect,
// or may not even compile.
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddArgument("--headless");
// Use this to specify non-standard Firefox install location.
options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\path\to\portable\firefox.exe");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```